# How to specify lifetime for a field that references another field in the same struct?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have the following code:

```rust
struct BufferPool {}

struct Buffer<'a> {
    pool: &'a BufferPool,
}

impl BufferPool {
    pub fn alloc(&self) -> Buffer<'_> {
        Buffer { pool: self }
    }
}

struct User {
    pool: BufferPool,
    buffer: Buffer<'what_lifetime_here?>,
}
```

The `buffer` object in the `User` struct is guaranteed to be `alloc`ated by the `pool` object in the same struct, as long as the `pool` object in the `User` struct is valid, `buffer` is valid too. But `buffer` requires a lifetime specifier, I am wondering if I can borrow the lifetime of the `pool` object for `buffer`, or do I have to lift the lifetime of the object that `buffer` depends on from the `pool` object to the `User` object like: `struct User<'a>`? Or there's another way around?

Comment: @cafce25 Actually I just read that post before posting the question, it's not the same, my question is about how to specify lifetime in this specific case.

Comment: The linked question is about what you try to do is not possible and why. So asking about how to do it can be answered with you can't.